# Time datatype not showing in the Crystal Report VS2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a weird problem with regards on Crystal Report bundled at visual studio 2010.
I'm trying to create a report which is the daily time record (TeacherID,date, time in, time out)

But after i include the table in the crystal report database expert, All **TIME** column not showing up. I tried several test if the cystal report is connected in the database for example i try to convert the TIME into DateTime then "Verify database" and oppps the Time columns (which is converted into DateTime) was shown up.

[image]

Structure of TeacherDTR in Crystal Reports

[image]

Structure in MSSQL Server

i tried to change TimeInAM from Time to DateTime
and  oppppssss

[image]

[image]

i'm going crazy for this and spends lots of time

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you are unable to see some of the columns in a table in database in crystal reports though they exist in database.

Follow the [link](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=777572) this might be helpful to you. As this link discuss the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer that works fine to me ..

when setting up the connection to the database i used sql server native client but it was wrong

the right one is Microsoft ole db sql provider for sql server