# SQL Server column type time(7) will not show up in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I am new to Crystal Reports. As I am bringing tables from my SQL Server database over to use in my report, I am noticing that any column of `Time(7)` type does not show up as a column in my Crystal Reports. These tables I am using have a lot of `time(7)` columns.

Is there a way to bring those column types into Crystal Reports?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 enterprise. I have just added on the latest CR_13_22 release.

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: `CAST` those values to strings on your query.

Comment: Have a look https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3236857

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031669/time-datatype-not-showing-in-the-crystal-report-vs2010